# How can I make a C++ typename nest itself and "infinitely" recurse?

Tags: c++, arrays, json, c++20, typename

Im trying to turn this piece of JSON into a C++ type using a neat little JSON parsing library I have created.

```
[
 "a",
   [
      "b",
      [
         "c",
         [  
            "d", 
            ["... so on so forth"] 
         ]
      ]
   ]
]
```

Currently, this is technically what the type would look like in C++, however this is obviously invalid as the typename cannot reference itself:

```cpp
typename std::variant<std::string, std::vector<requirements_type>> requirements_type;
```

Is there any way to make an infinitely recurring typename that can handle this sort of structure?

Comment: you do not need something infintely recurring. Eventually there will be an end to the nesting.

Comment: Is there a way to detect the amount of nesting and apply it to the typename?

Comment: You can achieve this with some form of indirection. For example put the variant in a `class` type and include a `unique_ptr` to that class type as a possible variant value type.

Comment: `std::vector` is already all the indirection you need to avoid an infinite size. Do not use an extra `std::unique_ptr` around it unless actually necessary. No, a type alias can't refer to itself; use a class. (I believe `std::vector<A>` is specified to be complete even when `A` is not, so `class A { std::variant<..., std::vector<A>> self; };` is allowed.) You can't "detect the amount of nesting" from a runtime value and apply it to a compile-time type... if you want to handle *any* input of this form without an arbitrary depth limit you *do* need unbounded recursion (or a different encoding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in 463035818_is_not_a_number's answer

Instead of using a `typename` I can use a `class` that references itself:

```cpp
struct RequirementArray {
    std::variant<std::string, std::vector<RequirementArray>> self;
};
```

I can recurse through this by using this simple method:

```cpp
void recurseAndOutput(RequirementArray array, int i) {
  try {
    std::vector<RequirementArray> requirementArrays = std::get<std::vector<RequirementArray>>(array.self);
    for (RequirementArray requirementArray: requirementArrays) {
      recurseAndOutput(requirementArray, i + 1);
    }
  } catch (std::bad_variant_access const & ignored) {
    std::string string = std::get<std::string>(array.self);
    printf("%s - %i", string.c_str(), i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Interestingly recurring without side-effects now.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in comments, you cannot have an infinetely nested type like your `requirements_type`. The size of objects of a type is finite. Also in practice your JSON will not be infintely nested. You need to stop the nesting somewhere.

A type alias cannot refer to itself, but you can refer to the class while declaring its members:

```
struct requirements_type {
    std::variant< std::string, std::vector< requirements_type > > data;
};
```

Comment: Again, a `std::unique_ptr` is not required. A `std::vector` can be empty, that's enough.

Comment: @HTNW indeed good point

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` is not a problem. It is better optimized if a zero or one is required.

Comment: @Red.Wave nobody said it would be a problem. Before the edit the answer had a `std::unique_ptr<std::variant< std::string, std::vector< requirements_type>>>` and thats unnecessary. OP doesnt want zero or one. They asked for N and N can already be 0